# Shared axis with gridspec subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using nested `GridSpecFromSubplotSpec` to create a nested grid of axes. I have two independent set of axes, a top one and a bottom one. Each set has four axes, arranged in a 2x2 grid.

Here is the code I'm using and the result I obtain:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gsp

fig = plt.figure()
global_gsp = gsp.GridSpec(2, 1)

for i in range(2):
    axes = np.empty(shape=(2, 2), dtype=object)
    local_gsp = gsp.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 2, subplot_spec=global_gsp[i])

    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            ax = plt.Subplot(fig, local_gsp[j, k],
                             sharex=axes[0, 0], sharey=axes[0, 0])
            fig.add_subplot(ax)
            axes[j, k] = ax

    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            ax = axes[j, k]
            x = i + np.r_[0:1:11j]
            y = 10*i + np.random.random(11)
            ax.plot(x, y, color=f'C{i}')
            ax.set_xlabel('x')
            ax.set_ylabel('y')


plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting figure]

As you can see, the top set has blue lines, the bottom set has orange lines, and the blue lines are well represented with the limits `[0, 1]x[0, 1]`, while the orange lines are represented with the limits `[1, 2]x[10, 11]`. When I create the subplots with `plt.Subplot`, I use the `sharex` and `sharey` arguments to have exactly the same scale on all four axes in each set (but different scale across different sets).

I would like to **aviod the repetition of the label and the ticks of each axis**. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subplot axes have functions `is_{first,last}_{col,row}()` (although I could not find the documentation anywhere) as shown in [this matplotlib tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html#a-complex-nested-gridspec-using-subplotspec). These functions are useful to only print the label(s) and/or ticks in the right spot. To hide the tick labels, [shared_axis_demo.py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/shared_axis_demo.html) recommends using `setp(ax.get_{x,y}ticklabels(), visible=False)`

```
fig = plt.figure()
global_gsp = gs.GridSpec(2, 1)

for i in range(2):
    axes = np.empty(shape=(2, 2), dtype=object)
    local_gsp = gs.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 2, subplot_spec=global_gsp[i])

    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            ax = plt.Subplot(fig, local_gsp[j, k],
                             sharex=axes[0, 0], sharey=axes[0, 0])
            fig.add_subplot(ax)
            axes[j, k] = ax

    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            ax = axes[j, k]
            x = i + np.r_[0:1:11j]
            y = 10*i + np.random.random(11)
            ax.plot(x, y, color=f'C{i}')


            #
            # adjust axes and tick labels here
            #
            if ax.is_last_row():
                ax.set_xlabel('x')
            else:
                plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)

            if ax.is_first_col():
                ax.set_ylabel('y')
            else:
                plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, creating a subplot with `sharex` and `sharey` as I did only guarantees that the limits will be the same for the linked axes, but does not turn off and label and tick labels. On the other hand, `plt.subplots` also turns these things off when it creates the grid. My interpretation is that matplotlib only turns off the labels if all axes are created at the same time.